# Extracting data from Yahoo Finance, getSymbols

Tags: r, return, quantmod

Do you know what happened with quantmod? The following code worket, but now it is not working.

```r
library(quantmod)
sp <- getSymbols("^GSPC", scr = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

Could you help me, please, how to update it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyquant` is built on top of `quantmod` and is gathering info from Yahoo Finance. Seems to be working.

```
library(tidyquant)

tq_get("^GSPC")

# A tibble: 2,531 × 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close     volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 ^GSPC  2013-01-02 1426. 1462. 1426. 1462. 4202600000    1462.
 2 ^GSPC  2013-01-03 1462. 1465. 1456. 1459. 3829730000    1459.
 3 ^GSPC  2013-01-04 1459. 1468. 1459. 1466. 3424290000    1466.
 4 ^GSPC  2013-01-07 1466. 1466. 1457. 1462. 3304970000    1462.
 5 ^GSPC  2013-01-08 1462. 1462. 1452. 1457. 3601600000    1457.
 6 ^GSPC  2013-01-09 1457. 1465. 1457. 1461. 3674390000    1461.
 7 ^GSPC  2013-01-10 1461. 1472. 1461. 1472. 4081840000    1472.
 8 ^GSPC  2013-01-11 1472. 1473. 1468. 1472. 3340650000    1472.
 9 ^GSPC  2013-01-14 1472. 1472. 1466. 1471. 3003010000    1471.
10 ^GSPC  2013-01-15 1471. 1473. 1464. 1472. 3135350000    1472.
# … with 2,521 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! But could you, please, how to install this package.
install.packages("tidyquant") is not working

library(tidyquant). 

Too many warnings

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Rtemp\RtmpIxOYZm\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages 'hardhat', 'furrr', 'pillar', 'htmlwidgets', 'recipes', 'rsample', 'plotly', 'tsfeatures', 'lifecycle', 'timetk', 'tidyselect', 'tidyquant'

Warning message in install.packages("tidyquant"):
"installation of package 'hardhat' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in

Comment: Are you using a VPN or on a corporate PC?

Comment: No. It's my laptop. I tried in RStudio and in Jupyter Notebook (without VPN). The mistake is the same.

Comment: I installed it through library("tidyquant", type = "binary"). However, tq_get("^GSPC") is not working. Error: Warning:
x = '^GSPC', get = 'stock.prices': Error in new.session(): Could not establish session after 5 attempts.

Comment: tidyquant is a wrapper around quantmod, so it's not an alternative if quantmod isn't working for the user.